# How to transform one numerical scale into another?

Tags: math

Let's say I have a numerical scale and I want to transform it into a different scale so that the relationship is proportional. For example, I have a scale from 2 to 6 and I want to transform it into another scale from 50 to 250, so that 4, which is the midpoint of the first scale, corresponds to 150, which is the midpoint of the second scale.

Does anyone know how this can be done mathematically for any two scales? What formula or equation must be applied to each element of the first scale to convert it into its corresponding of the second scale?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform it to `[0,1]` from `[a,b]` and then transform it to `[c,d]`.

```
x in [a,b] => y = (x-a)/(b-a) in [0,1]
y in [0,1] => z = (d-c)*y + c in [c,d]
```

Hence `x` to `z` is:

```
x in [a,b] => z = (d-c) * (x-a) / (b-a) + c in [c,d]
```

Comment: Although I think I have this solution before, but I cannot found it!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for